# Is there a way to make Voiceover start on the top HTML element of a webpage?

Tags: html, ios, accessibility, voiceover

I'm trying to build an accessible website that would work in Kiosk mode on iPads only. I'm using `role="text" aria-label="Double tap to go to page2"` to describe links ( tags) that lets you navigate through pages.

It reads fine on the link, but once you double tap on it and the new page loads, VoiceOver either reads a random HTML element or sometimes that same link that was tapped.

Comment: If you have a native anchor tag/link, `<a>`, VoiceOver users will already know they have to double tap on it to select it.  But I'm not sure about the other problem you're having.  When a page loads, the focus should go to a consistent place and VoiceOver will read whatever has the focus.

Comment: (continued)  I tried a random page with VO turned on.  When I select a link on the page that takes me to another page, sometimes the resulting VO focus is on the address bar and sometimes it's on the "reader available" button, which is next to the address bar, depending on how the page is formatted.  I then went to a page that normally has the initial focus on an input field but when viewed on iOS, the field doesn't reeive focus.  Perhaps because apple doesn't want the onscreen keyboard to display when a page loads.

Comment: @slugolicious, thank you for the insight. I think the problem is only occurring on the App I'm using to put the website in Kiosk mode. 
I tried on Safari and it behaves just like you described.